# How to plot the Neilian Parabola with Latex?

Tags: plot

I want to plot the Neilian Parabola with Latex. The problem of course is that at zero the curve has a singular point which leads to errors when trying to plot the curve.

I've already searched on the web for a good tutorial but there seems to be none. I would be very grateful for any help or hints!

Comment: As always on this site: show us some code.

Comment: What is Neilian Parabola? I don't want to google. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `pstricks`solution:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic=true,dimen=middle, arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.15,unit=1.5,plotpoints=100, labelsep=2ex}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-4)(5,4)
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-4)(5,4)[$x$,-120][$y$,-130]
 \psset{linecolor =IndianRed3, linewidth = 1.2pt}
 \parametricplot{-2.5}{2.5}{2*t^2 | t^3}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `dimen=middle` does not affect lines I think.

Comment: I don't know. I started from an old code that required it. Maybe  it's useful for the cusp w.r.t. the intersection of the axes (not checked, though). I'll see that later this day.